# Порядок включения заголовочных файлов по Google C++ Style Guide

Tags: c++, header

[Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes) предлагает в файлы имплементации (.cpp, .cc) включать заголовочные файлы следующим образом:

> In `dir/foo.cc` or `dir/foo_test.cc`, whose main purpose is to implement or test the stuff in `dir2/foo2.h`, order your includes as follows:
>
> ```
> dir2/foo2.h.
> A blank line
> C system files.
> C++ system files.
> A blank line
> Other libraries' .h files.
> Your project's .h files.
> ```

Как сказано по ссылке такой порядок позволяет в случае нехватки в `dir2/foo2.h` нужных зависимостей, увидеть ошибку сборки именно при компиляции текущего файла, когда это делает разработчик `foo`-функционала, а не где-то в другом месте неожиданно для других разработчиков. Вполне логично.

Но почему `Other libraries' .h files.` и `Your project's .h files.` помещены в конец? Ведь в них тоже теоретически могут отсутствовать необходимые зависимости, которые при таком порядке могут быть скрыты из-за включений `C system files.` и `C++ system files.`. Или же предполагается, что эти проблемы должны быть выявлены в других (соответствующих этим заголовочным файлам) файлах реализации? А как быть тогда с *header-only* библиотеками? Или здесь стоило ещё упомянуть требование отлаженности файлов из `Other libraries`? А может сокрытие зависимостей для других `.h files.` здесь наоборот благо? Типа того, чтобы заострить внимание на своих файлах, и максимально завуалировать проблемы в чужих?

Короче говоря, не будет ли порядок вида:

> ```
> dir2/foo2.h.
> A blank line
> Other libraries' .h files.
> Your project's .h files.
> A blank line
> C system files.
> C++ system files.
> ```

более подходящим для ускорения поиска скрытых зависимостей? Так же не очень ясно, рекомендуется ли тот же порядок включения сохранять внутри заголовочных (.h, .hpp) файлов.

Comment: это вопрос или для самоответа?

Comment: @VTT вопрос, конечно. Для самоответа публикация одновременно с вопросом делается :)